# Get all posts from Wordpress as JSON

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying ti get all the posts form my Wordpress website with the post_type "product".

I tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish');

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$array = array();

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    global $product;
    $array[] = array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'title' => get_the_title()
    );

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($array);
exit();
?>
```

Although when I add `'posts_per_page' => 450` to `$args`, it returns posts of the type, however if I add a value higher than 450 such as 500, it returns nothing again.

I am using this to loop through all product posts and add the name, price etc. to an array in the loop.

How do I fix the `$args` to get all the product posts.

**EDIT:**

I also recently tried:

```
<?php
    $args="SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.`post_type` = 'product' AND wp_posts.`post_status` = 'publish'";

    $loop = get_results( $args );

    $array = array();

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        global $product;
        $array[] = array(
            'id' => get_the_ID(),
            'title' => get_the_title()
        );

    endwhile;

   // wp_reset_query();
    ob_clean();
    echo json_encode($array);
    exit();
    ?>
```

Comment: While slightly off0topic, would using something like the [JSON API Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) work for you?

Comment: Did you create the custom post type "product" by calling register_post_type()?  If so, can you post that code?

Comment: Can you see if any product posts are returned if you remove the global $product line?

Comment: Are you intending to use this via ajax?

Comment: @eddiemoya No I am not. I just to have the product data as json on the page, the I read the data from the url for an external c# app. So all I need from this query is to have the all the products returned and their data displayed as json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check your table for data. Is there any post of post type products. if yes then the simple query should work

```
SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.`post_type` = 'product' AND $wpdb->posts.`post_status` = 'publish'
```

you can run this code in phpmyadmin directly. and see if any post is there. and please replace $wpdb with the prefix of you tables.

Comment: I tried `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.`post_type` = 'product' AND wp_posts.`post_status` = 'publish'` in phpmyadmin and it got the data correctly. However I tried in the php code and it returned nothing. Please see the code in my question above.

Comment: global $wpdb;
$args = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.`post_type` = 'product' AND $wpdb->posts.`post_status` = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.`ID`";
$loop = $wpdb->get_results( $args ); echo '<pre>';print_r($wpdb);echo '</pre>'; and tell me the output of $wpdb object so i can see what is wrong

Comment: I posted a screen shot in my question above please see. Also just in case, there's some of what's returned as text that I copied. Please see above

Comment: So when I tried this I code the some data returned. Where's the problem then? In structuring the loop to get the products as structured json? Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: it is working fine and data is coming. i can see that. now let me give you the code to loop against the product

Comment: global $wpdb; 
$args = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.ID"; 
$products = $wpdb->get_results( $args ); 
$output = array();
foreach( $products as $product){
 $output[] = array( 'id' => $product->ID, 'title' => $product->post_title );
}
echo json_encode( $output);

Answer (score 15):

No need to simulate the loop here. This is the most straightforward way:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'nopaging' => true 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); // $query is the WP_Query Object
$posts = $query->get_posts();   // $posts contains the post objects

$output = array();
foreach( $posts as $post ) {    // Pluck the id and title attributes
    $output[] = array( 'id' => $post->ID, 'title' => $post->post_title );
}
echo json_encode( $output );
```

Or you can leave out the `foreach` and just `echo json_encode( $posts );` to get all the properties of the posts.

Comment: I tried `$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'nopaging' => true, 'posts_per_page' => -1 );` but this returns empty. I get no product data returned in the array.

Comment: Try to take out `posts_per_page`. After all, you're asking for "no paging", right?

Comment: Tried it. It also returns empty. No data.

Comment: I think there must be some confusion here, since I get the results perfectly. I have updated my answer to give a complete script. Try it out.

Comment: ugh, Tried and still returns empty. I also tried outputting in the console and still nothing. The post type product, is being used as teh products use Woocommerce. Could this cause any issues with getting back the data? I mean when I use ` 'posts_per_page' => 450`, I get back product data but just not all as its over 600 products.

Comment: I have no idea about what WooCommerce might or might not do here. You could try to add `'suppress_filters' => true` to the `$args`. That will bypass the filters that might modify the query.

Comment: Same result.I can ask for as many as 470 posts but any more and the result would be empty

Comment: Just a sidenote: ID needs to be capitalized as ```$post->ID``` in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
//this file is in main folder and it works for me(yourWordpressWebsite.com/yourFile.php)

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type='post'");

echo json_encode($posts);
exit();
?>
```

output:
[{"ID":"1","post_title":"Hello world!"},{"ID":"63","post_title":"Blockquote Post"}...

Comment: How about getting thumbnails and custom post meta as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you show all posts in a query: `'posts_per_page' => -1` - so your query becomes:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: You should include some more detail / explanation for the OP

Comment: Happy Alex? :) And what is OP?

Comment: .. i meant explain the difference - (the => -1 part mainly)

OP is Original Poster

Comment: `-1` stands for all-posts in WordPress - nothing more.

Comment: @Banago I tried `$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );`, and it returns nothing on the page. Blank page

Comment: Can you provide more code from the page please. Show me the whole loop code.

Comment: $send_array should just be $array in json_encode($send_array);

Comment: @Banago That was a simple typo in adding the code to the question. That's not the problem. Still I get a plank page when I try -1. And that is all the code above in the question.

Comment: @Tester do you have WP_DEBUG set to true so it can show you what's wrong?

Comment: Try to set the "nopaging" variable in $args, i.e. $args = array( 'nopaging'=>'true' ), maybe pagination mess up custom posts returned results.

Comment: @bodi0 I tried that but then the array returns empty

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you need to get posts with manual query,

Just like this,

```
global $wpdb;
$args = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.`post_type` = 'product' AND $wpdb->posts.`post_status` = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.`ID`";
$loop = $wpdb->get_results( $args );
```

In my experience, `'posts_per_page' => -1` will not returns all the posts, i don't know why.
Somehow wordpress not returning more than `500` or `1000` posts from database...

Comment: I tried : `<?php

global $wpdb;
$args = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.`post_type` = 'product' AND $wpdb->posts.`post_status` = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.`ID`";
$loop = $wpdb->get_results( $args );

$array = array();

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    global $product;
    $array[] = array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'title' => get_the_title()
    );

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($array);
exit();
?>`

Comment: its not like that....

Just print `$loop`...you will get result array from `$$wpdb->get_results()`.

Comment: I also tried that it returned empty square brackets. So empty again

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a plugin developed for such a purpose. This one is listed on the WordPress.org website, and it seems like it may help you.

**[JSON API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)**

It's always best to check the WordPress.org hosted plugins first

Comment: this plugin is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'product' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

echo json_encode($myposts);

**I think this should work**

Comment: Got the same result when I tried this, it returned empty, got nothing back. And just as before, if I change the -1 to a number below 470, then it works and I get the results.

Comment: try use -1 like this '-1'