# How to use ACF into JSON via ajax in Wordpress

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use the Advanced Custom Field (ACF) plugin to return JSON via ajax in WordPress.

The below code correctly returns the JSON data of the posts but is not giving me the ACF data inside each post.

How can I get that ACF data into JSON?

**PHP File**

```
add_shortcode("owt-ajax-shortcode", "owt_wpl_run_shortcode");
function owt_wpl_run_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'views/owt-ajax-page-view.php';
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $template;
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "owt_include_scripts");
function owt_include_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
}
add_action("wp_ajax_owt_ajax_lib", "owt_lib_ajax_handler_fn");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_owt_ajax_lib", "owt_lib_ajax_handler_fn");
function owt_lib_ajax_handler_fn() {
    $param = isset($_REQUEST['param']) ? trim($_REQUEST['param']) : "";
    global $wpdb;
    if (!empty($param)) {
        if ($param == "get_all_posts") {
            $all_posts = get_posts(array(
              "post_type" => "post",
              "post_status" => "publish",
              'posts_per_page' => 20,
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'orderby' => 'date',
              'cat' => 66
              ));
            header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
            echo json_encode( $all_posts );
            die;
        }
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<button id="btn-get-all-posts">Click to get All Posts</button>
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        jQuery("#btn-get-all-posts").on("click", function () {
            var postdata = "action=owt_ajax_lib&param=get_all_posts";
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postdata, function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of use `get_posts` try your own query with `WP_Query`

here is an example code, please let me know if it works correctly(I didn't test it yet)

```
function owt_lib_ajax_handler_fn()
{
    $param = isset($_REQUEST[ 'param' ]) ? trim($_REQUEST[ 'param' ]) : "";
    if ( ! empty($param) ){
        if ( $param == "get_all_posts" ){
            $args          = [
                "post_type"      => "post",
                "post_status"    => "publish",
                "posts_per_page" => 20,
                "order"          => 'DESC',
                "orderby"        => 'date',
                "category__in"   => [ 66 ],
            ];
            $all_posts     = new WP_Query($args);
            $json_response = [];
            if ( $all_posts->have_posts() ){
                while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) {
                    $json_response[] = [
                        'title'    => get_the_title(),
                        'content'  => get_the_content(),
                        'acf_meta' => [
                            get_fields(get_the_ID()),
                        ],
                    ];
                }
                wp_send_json($json_response, 200);
                wp_die();
            }
            else {
                wp_send_json($json_response, 404);
                wp_die();
            }
        }
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: It gives Error : There has been a critical error on your website.

Comment: what line exactly have problem?

Comment: It does not shows the problem but when i remove the code under while loop($json_response[]=[ 'title' => get_the_title()..) and put echo "Testing" .. then it works fine

Comment: Solved my problem by this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730572/get-all-posts-from-wordpress-as-json) Thanks @ali-qorbani

Answer (score 0):

please have a look as below:

```js
$posts = get_posts(array(
 'numberposts' => -1,
 'post_type'  => 'post',
 'meta_query' => array(
  'relation'  => 'AND',
  array(
   'key'   => 'color',
   'value'    => array('red', 'orange'),
   'compare'  => 'IN',
  ),
  array(
   'key'    => 'featured',
   'value'    => '1',
   'compare'  => '=',
  ),
 ),
));
```

Comment: ACF don't have database so it will not helpful

Comment: then how would you get the ACF field data?

Comment: You must know the ACF key_name

Comment: Can you redefine my code with your code.. i just want to post data + acf json data with similar id that is (post_ID=acf_id) in single file

Comment: can you please share ACF field name?

Comment: {"id":3332,"acf":{"name":"example","type":"","last_date":""}}

Comment: Would you please also send $all_posts data to me?

Comment: {"ID":3332,"post_author":"1","post_date":"","post_date_gmt":"","post_content":""}

Comment: Thanks, as I can see in your code you're getting only post data but not getting related ACF field data, so for the ACF field have you created that field by custom code or using ACF plugin?

Comment: using acf plugin

Comment: Now I need that ACF filed name please share.
Please see screenshot: https://ibb.co/vZxFkXz

Comment: Name as "name" Last Date as "last_date" and so on

Comment: Okay, and in the Rules section what did you select? You must select Post Type is equal to Post and then edit any of post from admin which you have created and there you ACF Last date field will be appear

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_owt_ajax_lib", "owt_ajax_lib");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_owt_ajax_lib", "owt_ajax_lib");
function owt_ajax_lib() {
    $param = isset($_REQUEST['param']) ? trim($_REQUEST['param']) : "";
    global $wpdb;
    if (!empty($param)) {
        if ($param == "get_all_posts") {
            $args = [
                        "post_type"      => "post",
                        "post_status"    => "publish",
                        "posts_per_page" => 20,
                        "order"          => 'DESC',
                        "orderby"        => 'date',
                        "category__in"   => [ 33 ],
                    ];
            $all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
            $json_response = array();
            if ( $all_posts->have_posts() ):
                while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post();
                    $json_response[] = [
                        'title'    => get_the_title(),
                        'content'  => get_the_content(),
                        'acf_meta' => [
                            get_fields( get_the_ID() ),
                        ],
                    ];
                endwhile; 
            endif;
            echo json_encode($json_response);
            die;
        }
    }
    die;
}
```